# How do I select a SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The company I work for uses a bunch of different SQL servers and I was wondering how to select a different SQL server in the same script.

For example, I want to select data from a table on a database in server 1 and using that data to get data from another table on a database in server 2. I tried googling the solution but I couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You can set them up as linked servers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998(v=bts.10).aspx

then you syntax will be

```
SERVERALIAS.DBNAME.owner.TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fully qualified names (i.e. select * from [server].[database].[owner].[tablename])

Also, be sure to setup those servers as linked servers.  There are several articles online how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kyle & Flavio that You have to use four part naming convention to whatever server,database,table & column data like this:

Select * from [Servername].[Databasename].[Owner].[Tablename]

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner option is to set up Synonyms to your linked servers. This way, you alias the server, and therefore don't have to hard code the 4 parts into every query.

If you hard code and later change a server's name, you will have to hunt down every reference and update. With Synonyms, all you'll have to do is update the applicable Synonym.

Synonyms give you transparent external tables, procedures, and UDFs.

[MSDN here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)